# Reload page if address bar url does not match defined url

Tags: jquery

I have a website site page that people can reach using multiple urls. What I am trying to achieve is if people hit the url by another url, it automatically reloads the page to the correct url. If the correct url is reached first time, nothing happens. I have got the below to work which changes the URL but doesn't reload What I want it to do now is reload if if doesn't match, else stay as is. Can someone give me some pointers please?

Tried the code below with addition of reload but just gets stuck in reload cycle.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function (){
    history.pushState("", "", "http://test.com/test");
  });
</script>
```

Comment: You don't want pushState for this. You can determine the current page from the various properties exposed from `window.location`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location. That being said, I'd strongly suggest you do this on the server side, using some form of URL rewriting. It's more extensible, more reliable, and will not hinder your SEO like this would

Comment: As Rory suggested, I highly recommend you do this on the server side. Search for .htaccess redirections. This is also better for your SEO.

Comment: @VVV Just a note, but researching .htaccess will only be useful if it's an Apache web server.